# Unterschiedliche Rollen in einem Versicherungsvertrag

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request, legal-terminology

In an insurance contract, the roles must normally be precisely defined between:

1. The underwriter: the person who signs the insurance contract (and normally pays the insurance premium)
2. The insured: the person on whose head is the insured event of the contract
3. The beneficiary: the person who will receive the money in case the insured event of the insurance contract occurs.

In some cases, these three persons are the same, but not always. For instance, a grandmother (the "underwriter") could sign a life insurance contract so that her grandchildren (the "beneficiaries") receive some money in case the parents (the "insured" persons) die. This example is a bit theoretic, but it explains the concept.

What are the correct German words for these three different roles ? I have looked in various dictionaries like DUDEN but they mix a bit everything together, not distinghishing between "Versicherungsnehmer" and "Versicherte".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no [Versicherungskaufmann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufmann_f%C3%BCr_Versicherungen_und_Finanzen), but according to my experience with insurance contracts (and according to Wikipedia), the terminology is as follows:

The [Versicherungsnehmer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versicherungsnehmer) is the contractual partner for the insurance company. They typically pay the premiums and are the first contact for questions or problems the insurance company may have. That would be the *underwriter*.

The [versicherte Person](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versicherte_Person) is the person whose risk is insured. They may be or may be not identical with the Versicherungsnehmer. That would be the *insured*. You may find the term "mitversicherte Person". That's somebody whose risk is *also* insured, maybe the spouse or the kids of the "primary" versicherte Person.

The last term doesn't apply to a person im German, but to the *right* to receive money from the contract. That right is called [Bezugsrecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezugsrecht_(Versicherung)). The person who has this Bezugsrecht may be called "Bezugsberechtiger". That would be the *benificiary*. You may want to note that the term "Bezugsrecht" is also used in other fields, like stock markets or others.

Comment: I see no reason to switch to the term *Bezugsrecht* designating something different, when there are *Begünstigter* and *Anspruchsberechtigter*.

Comment: Hmm - personally, i would prefer _Begünstigter_ , too, but [§ 159 Versicherungsvertragsgesetz (VVG)](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/vvg_2008/__159.html) explicitly uses _Bezugsberechtigter_ and _Bezugsberechtigung_, respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much @Henning Kockerbeck for this detailed answer ! And thank you also guidot and tohuwawahu for your additions !